# Insufficient Privileges - Salesforce Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have insufficient privileges to create a trigger on an object in Salesforce

[image]

However, I am wondering where I can figure out what privileges I need?  Or which privileges I need to activate?  I am an administrator for my organization so I should have privileges.

For example, I have privileges to 'author apex'

[image]

What am I missing here?  What permissions do I need or need to enable in order to write a new trigger? Is it possible my organization doesn't have the correct license to allow that?

Comment: Is this object of yours a standard object, a custom object, or is it part of a managed package? Do you have an Enterprise or Unlimited edition org (I don't think Apex/triggers can be created on Essentials and Professional edition orgs)?

Comment: This is a custom object. We have the enterprise edition.